# Movie where a panel of psychic investigators try to discover who in the group is attempting to kill the others

Tags: story-identification, movie

I want to find this movie and watch it again. I believe I saw it as part of a series of sci fi films that were played on university of Iowa tv for a class of some kind, maybe in the early 80s. I think the movie had to be from the 50s or 60s maybe.

It is a science fiction movie in which a panel of psychic investigators try to discover who in the group is attempting to kill the others. Eventually they kill him, and he is stripped down to bare bones, but then rebuilds himself by force of will.

Comment: Good luck, you may want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if you can add any more details.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [The Power](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_(film)) (1968)

Professor Jim Tanner, a biochemist, discovers evidence of a person with psychic abilities among his co-workers in a research laboratory.

As Tanner tries to uncover the superhuman, his associates are methodically murdered.

Comment: That may be the one. I'll watch it tonight. Thanks for the tip!